# In Javascript string replace newline, carriage return chars with empty and replace literal sequences \n and \r with newline and carriage return chars

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript, I want to do multiple replace in a string as listed below.

1. Deelete all newlines and carriage returns
2. Replace literals \n with newline char
3. Replace literals \r with carriage return char

I want to achieve something like as below.

```
let str=
`line1\r\n
line2\n
line3\r`;

//I want to modify in first step to
`line1\r\nline2\nline3\r`;

//In second step I want to modify it to
`line1\r
line2
line3\r`;

//In third step I want to modify it to
`line1

line2
line3
`;
```

What is the best efficient way to do this?

Comment: `What is the best efficient way to do this?` the string replace method

Comment: @Someone - what does python have to do with it?

Comment: Its Javascript, not python. I have string stored in database, I need to convert after fetching data from database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you tried and explain any issues you had

Comment: What problem are you having? You should be able to do this with 3 simple `str.replace()` calls.

Comment: FYI if you want literal `\r` and `\n` in your strings, you need to escape the backslash. You also cannot have multi-line double / single quoted string literals. Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead

Comment: oops, misread the question -_- My point about `\r` and `\n` still holds, though.

Answer (score -1):

I had to use 3 str.replace to solve the issue as below.

```
let str = 
`line1\r\n
line2\n
line3\r`;

str = str.replace(/[\r\n]/gm, '');       //remove carriage return and newline with empty
str = str.replace(/(?:\\[r])+/g, '\r');  //remove \r literals with carriage return
str = str.replace(/(?:\\[n])+/g, '\n')   //remove \n literals with new line
```

I will be more interested to know if last two str.replace can be combined if at all possible.